# Can first order logic represent a past occurring adverbial dependent clause with a present main clause to form the perfect tense?

Tags: syntax, english, tense

Can [first order logic](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic) represent a past occurring adverbial dependent clause with a present main clause to form the perfect tense?

Is this the way to represent an adverbial dependent clause with first order logic?

I have existed since before Bill was born.

BEFORE(PAST(BORN(BILL)),PRESENT(IS(I)))

Since BORN(BILL) can be represented with BORN(e1,BILL) can first order logic represent E, R and U as described in this example for present perfect?

[image]

Comment: This is not propositional logic, which is the simplest formal logic, not even predicate logic, it’s a higher-order formalism. Aside from this, your formula is one way of expressing the sentence, but I’d consider using the Davidsonian notation, which is more elegant (and more straightforward).

Comment: @Atamiri   It's my first attempt.   I am very interested in seeing your examples.

Comment: I was attempting to use something from @jlawler - http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jlawler/logicguide.pdf

Comment: Davidsonian semantics is first-order, it uses “individuals” to denote predication, so “born(Bill)” becomes “born(e1, Bill)” and you can then say “past(e2, e1)” instead of “past(born(Bill))” (which isn’t first-order). It has a number of technical advantages but there’s no semantic difference.

Comment: That's only important for logicians. Formal logics are just stick-figure representations of certain aspects of natural language; it's clear that humans use all kinds of informal (and formally incorrect or incoherent) logics. And don't forget tense is a complication that logics don't often undertake. For one thing, tenses have a habit of presupposing, which predicate calculus can't handle -- just the assertions, ma'am. Lacking a real theory of time, tense is usually handled _ad hoc_.

Comment: @jlawler  In my reading it appears that there is no agreement whether or not present perfect is a tense or an aspect.     If I may be so bold to ask, what good is all of this is it's just a convenient way to document a particular view?  Is there such a thing as a "proof" like in mathematics?

Comment: Present perfect is a tense in Latin. Therefore it's called a tense in English grammar of the traditional sort. The actual facts are that there is a present tense and a past tense, which are inflected, and a Perfect construction, which uses an auxiliary _have_ and the past participle of the next verb. What is called "past perfect" is actually just the past tense of the Perfect construction. Constructions are not aspects, though they may indicate aspectual features, like the Perfect and Progressive constructions, though not all constructions do this.